# How to calculate shortest distance in polar coordinates when approaching a pole

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Given a distance (generally, a large one, say of 850km), a polar coordinate on the earth, and a bearing (with respect to the north pole), I'm using the Haversine formula to calculate a second coordinate. However, as I approach a pole, the shortest distance becomes tangential to that pole (at least I think so--correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not a mathematician, but a programmer, so bear with me while I lay out my formula and the results:

```
φ2 = arcsin(sin(φ1) * cos(850000/6371000) + cos(φ1) * sin(850000/6371000) * cos(bearing)) * (180 / π)
λ2 = (λ1 + arctan(sin(bearing) * sin(850000/6371000) * cos(φ1), cos(850000/6371000) - sin(φ1) * sin(φ2))) * (λ2 - π) * (180 / π)
```

I also have a formula that resets the coordinates to 180/-180 degrees when they cross either threshold, but I'm not entirely sure how to represent that mathematically.

Given a starting latitude and longitude (83.8047036171331, -27.8616033804678), I convert to radians and iterate from -180 degrees bearing to 180 degrees bearing, finding coordinates at 850km from my starting coordinate. I'm hoping to have a polygon as an end result. Here are my numbers divided by quadrant with respect to bearing:

```
-180.0 : 76.1604699668239, -27.8616033804677  
-165.0 : 76.2781247730064, -36.2069893102399  
-150.0 : 76.6289215559029, -44.5762730745583  
-135.0 : 77.2063944341844, -52.9975787393726  
-120.0 : 77.9998819868466, -61.5087265207167  
-105.0 : 78.994667035189, -70.1659285755627  

-90.0 : 80.1720895006312, -79.0598803856636  
-75.0 : 81.5094837735314, -88.3495571649968  
-60.0 : 82.9795366250911, -98.3431131407785  
-45.0 : 84.5477083040733, -109.725327457386  
-30.0 : 86.1617477729691, -124.353651321838  
-15.0 : 87.6953134517602, -148.975376057487  

0.0 : 88.5510627325576, 152.138396619532  
15.0 : 87.6953134517602, 93.2521692965516  
30.0 : 86.1617477729691, 68.6304445609022  
45.0 : 84.5477083040733, 54.0021206964505  
60.0 : 82.9795366250911, 42.619906379843  
75.0 : 81.5094837735314, 32.6263504040613  

90.0 : 80.1720895006312, 23.3366736247281  
105.0 : 78.994667035189, 14.4427218146272  
120.0 : 77.9998819868466, 5.7855197597812  
135.0 : 77.2063944341844, -2.72562802156294  
150.0 : 76.6289215559029, -11.1469336863772  
165.0 : 76.2781247730064, -19.5162174506955  
180.0 : 76.1604699668239, -27.8616033804677
```

As you can see, once I get to about 85 degrees N, the numbers start to increase precipitously. Now I understand in a very basic sense that the curve of a great circle has to do with its relationship to a pole and that a pole is a kind of coordinate singularity. Now my question is, how do I calculate a point that should, reasonably it seems, transverse a pole? Is the haversine formula inadequate in this regard and if so, is there another methodology for calculating a transpolar location? I apologize in advance if some of my vocab is off! Like I said I'm an amateur with interest in Mathematics but without much of a formal education!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The Haversine formula computes distance, not area. The distance is a scalar, it can't be tangential to anything. Are you asking how to compute the great circle distance between two points near the poles?

Comment: Sorry--I realize that was confusing. Given a point, I'm trying to find the nearest point 6500km from that point at any given bearing.

Comment: The bearing is with respect to North? (Presumably the point is not exactly on the pole.)

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: You might want to update your question, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you trying to compute the distance between two given points or trying to find a point at a given distance and bearing?

Comment: I hope that helps. Thank you for your interest in this.

Comment: Thanks! Let me look and see if I can understand what it going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked the formula, but you have ${850000 \over 6371000}$ instead of
either ${8500000 \over 6371000}$ or ${8500 \over 6371}$.

The point for the -180 bearing in the data above is about 750 km south of the center location.
(I believe the correct coordinates are about $(-96.1953,    -75.7800)$.)

It is not clear to me how you are computing your new coordinates. The Haversine formula is used to compute the distance given two sets of coordinates and does
not have a trivial inverse. Perhaps you can provide a link?

Here is one way to do it, I am sure there must be better ways:

I am performing the computations in the x-y-z plane rather than using
latitude/longitude. The mapping between the two is straightforward.

Given a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ on the surface of the earth excluding the poles, a bearing $\beta$ (measured clockwise from north) and a distance $L$,
compute a new point $p'$ a distance $L$ away from $p$ at bearing $\beta$ (from $p$).

Note that the poles are excluded so that the bearing makes sense, at either pole a bearing to/from North makes no sense.

I am assuming a perfectly spherical Earth. To reduce notational clutter,
 define
$u: \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by $u(x) = {1 \over \|x\|} x$ (that is, normalise $x$).

Let $R= \|p\|$, be the radius (of the idealised Earth), and let $N=(0,0,R)$ be the porth pole.

Note that a distance $L$ corresponds to an angle (at the Earth's center) of
$\alpha = {L \over R}$ (radians).

Compute a 'local north direction' $\nu = u(N-{1 \over R^2}\langle p, N \rangle p)$. This is a direction contained in the intersection of the tangent plane at $p$ with the subspace containing $p$ and $N$.

Compute a 'local east direction' $e = u(\nu \times p)$. This is a
direction perpendicular to both $\nu$ and $e$ with the appropriate
orientation.

(Note that $\nu, p, e$ are mutually orthogonal.)

Compute a 'local direction' $d = (\sin \beta) e + (\cos \beta) \nu$.
This is a unit vector in the direction we want to go in on the tangent
plane at $p$.

Then we have the new point $p' = (\cos \alpha) p + (\sin \alpha) R d$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the detailed response. I'm going over it right now, but in the meantime, here's how I calculate the longitude at 180 programatically: `var lat2 = φ2 * (180 / π)
            var long2 = (λ2 - π) * (180 / π)
 
            if long2 > 180 {
                long2 = -180 + (long2 % 180)
            } else if long2 < -180 {
                long2 = 180 + (long2 % 180)
            }`

Comment: Here's a link to the other computations that I followed: "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point":
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: After grinding through the formulae, it seems that they end up being the same. You need to fix the ${d \over R}$ part of your formulae (the current values above are off by a factor of 10). (As an aside, the formulae above are related to, but are not, the Haversine formula.)

Comment: Sorry--I don't understand--the same as what?

Comment: The procedure I described above ends up being the same as the formula you used in your question (subject to the ${ d \over R}$ thing).

Comment: Minor aside, it would be better if you used `atan2` instead of $\arctan$ as it will handle the 180 stuff for you.

Comment: Ok, but then I still have the same issue, I think. Say, I'm at 89 degrees latitude and plug the same distance into the formula, I end up with coordinates: @ -180 bearing: 81.3, @ -90: 82.3, @ 0: 83.3, @ 90: 82.2, @ 180: 81.3. It seems to me that's spiraling around the pole, right?

Comment: I need more info. to understand what you are doing in the last comment (starting lat/long., bearing, distance).

Comment: Starting Latitude/Longitude 89/-27, bearing is iterated over from -180 to 180 degrees, distance: 850000

Comment: 850,000 m or 850,000 km?

Comment: Sorry about that! Meters.

Comment: Those numbers look OK to me. At 89 latitude, you are about 110 km from the pole, so a circle of radius 850 km will certainly encircle the pole.

Comment: They look ok to me, too. What I'm looking for is a way to calculate distance across a pole.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'calculate distance across a pole'?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to ask the right question, but I'll give it one more shot. Let's say I'm a pilot and I'm approaching the pole from 89 degrees latitude. If I want to travel 850km past that point, I would not fly 850km in a spiral toward the pole.

Comment: Are you asking what direction you must fly in to follow a great circle route? That's not difficult, but is a completely different question than you have asked above. If you pick a bearing of zero and a distance of 850 km, then the above computation will compute the lat/long. of your destination. You fly north, don't change direction as you pass the pole and then fly directly south until you have covered 850 km. There is no spiral involved in any of this?

Comment: Listen--I know it's frustrating to answer questions for amateurs that don't really know what they're looking for, but to be fair I did ask in my question whether or not my approach was the right one at all. I must not have been clear enough about what I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to convey frustration. I'm just not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's ok. I'm just frustrated with myself because I'm not able to articulate what I want properly. Let me try again. If I'm any point on the globe 850 km away from a pole or more I can select a bearing, plug in a coordinate and a distance of 850km into the equation and get a second point that's 850km away from it. If I'm within 850km of a pole and do that I get a line that spirals toward the pole. I don't know how to use my equation to calculate a line that doesn't spiral toward a pole, or how I would go about doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't follow. The formula gives you a point. How are you getting a line/spiral? For example, if you are at $(83.8047036171331, -27.8616033804678)$, select 0° bearing and a distance of 850 km, the above calculation will give you a point $(88.559,152.138)$. You can see that $180-27.8616033804678 \approx 152.138$ so we are on the correct longitude on the other side of the pole, and the distance corresponds to an arc of around $7.6358°$, which brings you to $180-(83.805+7.6358) \approx 88.559$.

Comment: OK! I think I understand it now. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: I hope it helped. Ask if you don't understand.